# Files are Accepted not Queued

Tags: jquery, dropzone.js

Using DropzoneJS v4.0.

Below are the options that are set for the dropzone.

```
Dropzone.options.myDropzone = {
    acceptedFiles: '.jpg,.jpeg,.png',
    addRemoveLinks: true,
    autoQueue: false,
    clickable: false,
    maxFiles: 1,
    maxThumbnailFilesize: 2000,
    parallelUploads: 10,
    thumbnailWidth: null,
    thumbnailHeight: null,
    init: function() {
        var dropzone = this;

        dropzone.on("addedfile", function(file) {
            if (!file.type.match(/image.*/)) {
                dropzone.removeFile(file);
            }else {
                function();
            }
        });

        dropzone.on("maxfilesexceeded", function(file) {
            dropzone.removeFile(file);
        });

        dropzone.on("removedfile", function(){
            if($('#imgEditor').find('img').length == 0) {
                $('.overlay').remove();
                $('#cropper').remove();
                $('#upload').remove();
            }
        });

        $(document).on('click', '#upload', function(){
            dropzone.processQueue();
        });
    }
};
```

When I click the upload button that is dynamically generated from the `function()` in the `addedfile` event nothing happens. Checking `dropzone.getAcceptedFiles().length` returns the number of files in the dropzone, but checking `dropzone.getQueuedFiles().length` returns 0. No files have been uploaded or have triggered an upload and the file types are valid file types.

I need help understanding why a file would be considered accepted, but not queued. I haven't found documentation explaining a difference if there is any and in the code it looks like if a file is accepted it is supposed to be queued, but this is not the case. So I know why `processQueue` actually fails I just don't know why queueing is failing.

Changing `autoQueue` to true allows the file to be uploaded correctly, but this is not the desired affect. Please see [Enyo FAQ Dropzone Submit Button](https://github.com/enyo/dropzone/wiki/Upload-all-files-with-a-button).

Git
[#989](https://github.com/enyo/dropzone/issues/989#issuecomment-117267374)

Answer (score 2, accepted):

`autoQueue` does just that: it queues your file when it's added. Since you disabled it, it's not queued.

I think what you are looking for is: `autoProcessQueue: false` which won't upload the file unless you actually process the queue "manually".